# JQuery Active Class Error when page is not in navbar

Tags: jquery, .net

I have this script adds an active class to a navbar link based upon the current page. The issue that I am having is it throws off an error when I access a page not in the navigation bar. The error is '$' is undefined. So I am assuming since it can't find the page name in the navbar, it is throwing an error.

I am using a .net master page. I have this script along with the navbar in the master page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var current = location.pathname;
    $('.nav li a').each(function(){
        var $this = $(this);
        if ($this.attr('href').indexOf(current) !== -1) {
            $this.addClass('active');
        } else {
            $(this).removeClass( "active" );
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: And what error is saying?

Comment: $('.nav li a') .length==0 after that you can iterate

Comment: Just a side note : $this not a good variable name. Ignorance is Bliss though.

Comment: the sole purpose of using $ with variable is to identify that its not the DOM element but the jquery object,but you destroying the purpose by using $this

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have jquery installed properly on the page.
If not include this before any of your scripts.

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
```